# Not enough permissions to access API request https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, hybridauth

I am using following code for linkedin authentication and getting following error

Signed API request to https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me has returned an error. HTTP error 403. Raw Provider API response: {"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET /me","status":403}. Try again

Please help me where i am doing wrong?

I have got required permissions in the developer portal
[image]

- I tried changing scope parameters it did not work. Currently I am using parameters profile and email.Please find the github link https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/blob/master/src/Provider/LinkedIn.php